# Log into a SQL Server database as a different Windows user in Mule from Anypoint Cloudhub

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, mule

I want to log into an SQL Server database from Mule as a Windows User which has been setup as a generic support user and uses Windows authentication.  This Windows user is in a different domain to my personal Windows user account and will use different username and password to me.

Is this possible and if so how would you get it to work in a Mule workflow?  I am currently using the generic database connector with integrated security set to true but it looks like it keeps trying to log into the specified database with my credentials and not the username and password I am passing to it in the JDBC string.

When the workflow is complete the Mule project will be run in Anypoint Cloudhub.

Thanks

Comment: Windows authentication always uses the currently logged user credentials in the DB. To keep using it, the process that opens the connection must be run as the intended user. Either run the whole software as another user or spawn a helper process for the DB connection with alternative credentials.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can launch a process with `runas /netonly` to supply alternative credentials to be used for NTLM authentication.

See, eg
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3250/connect-to-sql-servers-in-another-domain-using-windows-authentication/

You can also do this by caching a credential with the Windows Credential Manager, but that would cause your Windows account to always use the alternative credentials.

Comment: I will be using this in Anypoint Cloudhub Mulesoft's cloud offering so will not be run locally.  Is there a way of getting something similar working with Cloudhub?